# How to set title color in ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

How to set title color in `ActionBarSherlock`?

Which theming attributes should I use?

Comment: Color of the text (title); or color of the bar?

Comment: <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item> I am using min version 7, the above andriod: prefix is not supporting getting error required min sdk version 11.There is any other suggetion to set title bar background color or image.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From the [ActionBarSherlock website](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html)

**Parent Themes**

> In order for the custom action bar implementation to function your application must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, or Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or your custom theme must use one of the aforementioned as its parent.

**Mirrored Attributes**

> Due to limitations in Android's theming system any theme customizations must be declared in two attributes. The normal android-prefixed attributes apply the theme to the native action bar and the unprefixed attributes are for the custom implementation...

In short, that means you need to leave out the `android:` prefix when you're styling the `ActionBar`.

**Theming the title color**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="YOURTHEME" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle</item>
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
<item name="titleTextStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
<item name="textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**NOTE**

I haven't tested this. Also, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) You should searching before posting on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) in the future.

Comment: Yes, I know but I didn't find about the "titleTextStyle" attribute, thanks!

Comment: It is not necessary, you can delete it

Comment: There are 2 errors on android:actionBarStyle and android:titleTextStyle: "android:actionBarStyle requires API level 11 (current min is 10)". How to overcome this?

Comment: If your minSdkVersion is less than 11, you will need two files: values/styles.xml and values-v11/styles.xml. The android:-prefixed items should go into values-v11/styles.xml.

Answer (score 43):

You can easily do this with

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>App Name</font>"));
```

Comment: Good answer. Works in all levels of api's without any problem.

Comment: After dealing with styles and NOT getting it working with that (after really sifting through SO!) - this method worked! Thank you!

Comment: simple and effective!

Comment: Looks simple and elegant answer.  But doesn't work for me.. don't know why.

Answer (score 24):

i have changed the title color of this way:

in the Styles.xml file, i have added these styles

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/CustomTitleColorBar</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/CustomTitleColorBar</item>
</style>

<!-- Style for the color title bar -->
<style name="CustomTitleColorBar" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

the last thing that i did was set the theme in the activity:

**public static int THEME = R.style.Theme_Styled;**

this line goes before super.onCreate() method

**setTheme(THEME);**

this is it.

Comment: Do you need the "@style/" in the parent styles or would it also work without?

Comment: How do I change the background with this solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it from 2 places either in style.xml or programatically
1.From style.xml

2.Or in code

```
int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");  
TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(titleId);
yourTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor));
```

Or using actionbar you can also achieve this

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>App Name</font>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to change the text color that is on the **Menu**, not the color of text that is in the **Title** in **ActionBarSherlock**.

When you use `getSupportActionBar().SetTitle("My Title")` to style this text you should use the code `@Archie.bpgc`. His answer is correct, but I believe that you are in need of the following code:

```
<style name="MyTheme.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

See that you simply exchange `parent =" TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">` with `parent = "TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">`