# Change background color of ActionBarSherlock programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget, android-actionbar

I have an ActionBarSherlock on my form.  I'm reading style information at runtime.  One of the pieces of style is the background color of the ActionBar.  How can I change this at runtime?  The color can be any RGB value.

Comment: Look to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064411/change-actionbarsherlock-background-color

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this help : [How to set title color in ActionBarSherlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352022/how-to-set-title-color-in-sherlock-actionbar) via style
or  `getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ad_action_bar_gradient_bak));` via programmatically

**With the theme**

```
// add theme in app
<application android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>

// MainTheme
<style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">       
</style>

// MainThemeGreen
<style name="MainThemeGreen" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MainTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>        
</style>

// ActionBar
<style name="MainTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_green_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MainTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

// Text style
<style name="MainTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
</style>

// bg_green_actionbar.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ff74af3b" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

After this you can change Theme on fly: setTheme(R.styles.MainThemeGreen);

Comment: You are still specifying a local drawable resource.  I need to do it for any color that presented to me from a web service.

Comment: I see your new edit but I'm not following how this helps. After the app starts, I call a web service and it returns a color.  Say it is #123456.  How do I apply that to your hard coded #FF74af3b?

Answer (score 6):

One way:

```
mSupportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
mSupportActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff123456));
```

where `0xff123456` is your required ARGB integer.

Answer (score 5):

I just used below Code

```
 getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
   ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00853c")));
```

it changed the bg color. Hope, it helps.