# Change ActionBar text color

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to change my ActionBar color to blue (#0c01e3). My code is working because the actionbar background property is doing its job. But the text won't change. Any ideas? I'm using ABS.

```
<style name="MyActionBar1" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">#06e301</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">#06e301</item>
        <item name="android:background">#06e301</item>
        <item name="background">#06e301</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">#B9001F</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#0c01e3</item>
        >
```

[image]

### Update

:

[image]

Comment: Which text are you trying to change? Are you trying to change the text of the ActionItems,Tabs, or spinner text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352022/how-to-set-title-color-in-actionbarsherlock Check out this post.

Comment: It looks like I need to not include the proceeding "android:" but I get an error. I'm updating my question with a picture now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionBar text color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the theme, there is an attribute, `actionItemTextColor`, which controls this color.

Remember to specify it with and without the `android:` prefix when using ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: `<item name="android:actionItemTextColor">#ffffff</item>` doesn't work. Are you telling me to go into the ABS theme and change it?

Comment: actionbarsherlock.com has more than enough to get by.

Answer (score 2):

Set this in your `Java` Page .It works for me

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();    
 ab.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>App Name</font>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

add this and then try

```
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve on the answer of @IntelliJ Amiya:

```
    getActionBar().setTitle(
            Html.fromHtml("<font color='" + getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color) + "'>"
                    + getString(R.string.title_home) + "</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change that using xml ... 
This is what worked for me ...

```
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/titleBarBgColor</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/EldTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/EldTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/titleBarBgColor</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/EldTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/EldTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="EldTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/titleBarTextColor</item>
</style>
```