# Styling ActionBar Sherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to customize my sherlock action bar, but nothing that I code in my style.xml is recognized.

In my manifest file:

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
```

My style.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#222222</item>
    <item name="android:height">64dip</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>
</style>
```

I'm calling my actionbar this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

 com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar actionbar;

 ...

 actionbar = getSupportActionBar();

 ... }
```

There is no problem in showing the actionbar, but the same does not show any customization coded in style.xml, can someone help me? Thankful.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE !!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623805/actionbarsherlock-stacked-action-bar-styling-issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you are applying the same original style in the manifest file `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"` which doesn't make any difference.  You have prepared the custom style with name `Theme.MyAppTheme`, having parent as `Theme.Sherlock`. So, you need to declare your customized style(Theme.MyAppTheme) in your manifest file like `android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme"`. Even you have to include without android prefix attributes too like below as the other answerer also said. Hope this helps. Even you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104091/is-there-a-way-to-set-actionbar-backgound-by-image-in-android/14104260#14104260) too.

```
 <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar</item>        
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#222222</item>
    <item name = "background">#222222</item> 
    <item name="android:height">64dip</item>
     <item name="height">64dip</item>

    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
<item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="textColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>
        <item name="textSize">32sp</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: @Appu it there way to use this for applications with min sdk version  8?

Comment: @pepela It obviously runs on version 8. It works on Android 2.x and up. You can check [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/AndroidManifest.xml) for confirmation i.e, minSdkVersion is 7, so it runs even on 7 too. Hope your doubt is cleared.

Comment: @Appu it writes this error `android:actionBarStyle requires API level 11 (current min is 8)`

Comment: @pepela Then you didn't include actionBarSherlock library in your project, did you? Because if it shows that error, it gives warning about the original actionbar which is provided in API level 11.

Answer (score 3):

Use this and you don't need to create your own style

[Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar</item>
```

is for the default ActionBar, notice the 'android:'.
You have to style it like this:

```
     <resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#222222</item>
        <item name="android:height">64dip</item>
        <item name="background">#222222</item>
        <item name="height">64dip</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>
        <item name="textColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="textSize">32sp</item>
    </style>
```