# How to modify the height of tabs in android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-tabhost

**What i have in context** :: I have a Sherlock actionbar tab set-up here

---

**What i am trying to do**::

[image]

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    // Declare Variables
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set the view from main_fragment.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.main_fragment_desc_list_view);

        // Locate android.R.id.tabhost in main_fragment.xml
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        // Create the tabs in main_fragment.xml
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent);

        // Create Tab1 with a custom image in res folder
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Rating"), 
                SortByRatingDescListView.class, null);

        // Create Tab2
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Price"),
                SortByPriceDescListView.class, null);

        }
}
```

---

***Note***:: Code is functional without adding below line of code(reducing height)

### How to reduce the height of tab ?

**I tried with** ::

```
//Setting custom height for the tabs
final int height = 45;
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = height;
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = height;
```

**But i got the error as**::

```
        01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.findmybuffet/com.findmybuffet.restaurant_module.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.findmybuffet.restaurant_module.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-31 15:40:58.270: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  ... 11 more
```

---

### Is there another way to reduce the height of the tab .... when it comes to fragmented tabs ?

Thanks,

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14116480/3020568